# How to store data to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a controller named 'register' with action 'store'. The 'store' method have two instance variable called '@name' and '@age'. And
I have a model file named 'person.rb'. Now, How I share the instance variable in controller to model. And how to store data stored in database.

Comment: Show us your existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store it in the database you will need to

```
Person.create(age: @age, name: @name)
```

Comment: where to add this line ? In controller or model ?

Comment: you need to add it in the controller, where you have the instance variables

Comment: There is no code in my person.rb file. Is it ok ?

Comment: nope.. you need to first run a migration file that creates person tables in the DB and create a model for it.

You can do it by running rails g model Person age:integer name:string

Comment: and of course run rake db:migrate after that.